# Should I use a constructor or curly braces for object creation in linq's select method?

Tags: c#, linq

example:

```cs
var list = ApplicationContext.Employees
    .Select(x => new Employee()
    {
        FirstName = x.FirstName,
        LastName = x.LastName
    });
```

```cs
var list = ApplicationContext.Employees
    .Select(x => new Employee(
        x.FirstName,
        x.LastName
    ));
```

With the addition of nullable types, it seems better to just create a constructor for your dto. Then you do not have to deal with nullable warnings.

Should you use a constructor or curly brackets in select?

Is there a performance difference to the two approaches?

Comment: The second one will not even compile.

Comment: How is "nullable warnings" relevant here? Please show an example.

Comment: In general it's good to make your types immutable if possible which generally means using a constructor (although you COULD use `init` properties).

Comment: @mason this was a bit of a stretch but from `ApplicationContext` name I think my guess is highly likely being correct. And yes, for `IEnumerable` it will work (and for `IQueriyble` - will not - change snippet to `employees.AsQueryable()`). Added new comment to reflect the assumption.

Comment: P.S. If you are using some kind of ORM like EF Core it will not even compile if you use correct syntax - `new Employee( FirstName: x.FirstName, LastName: x.LastName )` because named arguments are not supported by expression trees.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With addition of [`required`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/required) modifier in C# 11 you can use the dtos without warnings and ctor:

> The `required` modifier indicates that the field or property it's applied to must be initialized by an object initializer. Any expression that initializes a new instance of the type must initialize all required members. The `required` modifier is available beginning with C# 11. The `required` modifier enables developers to create types where properties or fields must be properly initialized, yet still allow initialization using object initializers

```cs
public class Employee
{
    public required string FirstName { get; init; }
    public required string LastName { get; init; }
}
```

So the compiler will control if you have not initialized the corresponding property (i.e. something like `new Employee(){FirstName = x.FirstName}` will not compile).

[Demo @sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCDMACciCiBbADgGwPYE8BTQ2Ab1kUoUQCdCBHAVwEs6ATZCABkQDFWAzgBcAcgEN0hRKUQBzQkIDciZgDtmSxAF8KVJHSatCHEN0QAZMcPGTpchcrUblOmJWRJTPS9YmEA6hoAFv5iNOqqsnbymk6arlpAA==)